# calling 2 methods from onclick c#

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access-2013

Ive been trying to pass 2 SQL queries by clicking the button once and so this is what ive been trying to do as shown below but its not working....please help... thanks in advance

so this the code in front

`<asp:Button ID="btnWedRecInsert" runat="server" Text="Insert" OnClick="btnWedRecInsert_Click1; btnWedRecInsert_Click2;" />`

The code behind is below

```
protected void btnWedRecInsert_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 

    string Function = ddlFunction.Text;
    string FunctionDate = txtFunctionDate.Text;
    string FunctionTime = ddlFunctionTime.Text;
    string groomName = txtGroomName.Text;
    string groomFatherName = txtGroomFatherName.Text;
    string groomAge = txtGroomAge.Text;
    string groomPhone = txtGroomPhone.Text;
    string groomAddress = txtGroomAddress.Text;
    string brideName = txtBrideName.Text;
    string brideFatherName = txtBrideFatherName.Text;
    string brideAge = txtBrideAge.Text;
    string bridePhone = txtBridePhone.Text;
    string brideAddress = txtBrideAddress.Text;
    string registerName = txtRegisterName.Text;
    string registerPhone = txtRegisterPhone.Text;
    string registerAddress = txtRegisterAddress.Text;
    string referenceName = txtReferenceName.Text;
    string referencePhone = txtReferencePhone.Text;
    string referenceAddress = txtReferenceAddress.Text;



    string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MandapamDatabase"].ConnectionString;
    OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connString);
    string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO wedding(RegisteredDate, Function, FunctionDate, FunctionTime, groomName, groomFatherName, groomAge, groomPhone, groomAddress, brideName, brideFatherName, brideAge, bridePhone, brideAddress, registerName, registerPhone, registerAddress, referenceName, referencePhone, referenceAddress) VALUES( @Date, @Function, @FunctionDate, @FunctionTime, @groomName, @groomFatherName, @groomAge, @groomPhone, @groomAddress, @brideName, @brideFatherName, @brideAge, @bridePhone, @brideAddress, @registerName, @registerPhone, @registerAddress, @referenceName, @referencePhone, @referenceAddress) ";
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
    command.Connection = connection;
    command.CommandText = insertQuery;
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", DateTime.Now.Date);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Function", Function);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FunctionDate", FunctionDate);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FunctionTime", FunctionTime);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@groomName", groomName);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@groomFatherName", groomFatherName);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@groomAge", groomAge);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@groomPhone", groomPhone);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@groomAddress", groomAddress);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@brideName", brideName);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@brideFatherName", brideFatherName);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@brideAge", brideAge);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bridePhone", bridePhone);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@brideAddress", brideAddress);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@registerName", registerName);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@registerPhone", registerPhone);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@registerAddress", registerAddress);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@referenceName", referenceName);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@referencePhone", referencePhone);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@referenceAddress", referenceAddress);


    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        lblMessage.Text = "Record inserted successfully";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblMessage.Text = "Unable to insert record";
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
}


    protected void btnWedRecInsert_Click2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Function = ddlReception.Text;
        string FunctionDate = txtReceptionDate.Text;
        string FunctionTime = ddlReceptionTime.Text;
        string groomName = txtGroomName.Text;
        string groomFatherName = txtGroomFatherName.Text;
        string groomAge = txtGroomAge.Text;
        string groomPhone = txtGroomPhone.Text;
        string groomAddress = txtGroomAddress.Text;
        string brideName = txtBrideName.Text;
        string brideFatherName = txtBrideFatherName.Text;
        string brideAge = txtBrideAge.Text;
        string bridePhone = txtBridePhone.Text;
        string brideAddress = txtBrideAddress.Text;
        string registerName = txtRegisterName.Text;
        string registerPhone = txtRegisterPhone.Text;
        string registerAddress = txtRegisterAddress.Text;
        string referenceName = txtReferenceName.Text;
        string referencePhone = txtReferencePhone.Text;
        string referenceAddress = txtReferenceAddress.Text;



        string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MandapamDatabase"].ConnectionString;
        OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connString);
        string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO wedding(RegisteredDate, Function, ReceptionTime, FunctionDate, FunctionTime, groomName, groomFatherName, groomAge, groomPhone, groomAddress, brideName, brideFatherName, brideAge, bridePhone, brideAddress, registerName, registerPhone, registerAddress, referenceName, referencePhone, referenceAddress) VALUES( @Date, @Function, @FunctionDate, @FunctionTime, @groomName, @groomFatherName, @groomAge, @groomPhone, @groomAddress, @brideName, @brideFatherName, @brideAge, @bridePhone, @brideAddress, @registerName, @registerPhone, @registerAddress, @referenceName, @referencePhone, @referenceAddress) ";
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = insertQuery;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", DateTime.Now.Date);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Function", Function);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FunctionDate", FunctionDate);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FunctionTime", FunctionTime);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@groomName", groomName);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@groomFatherName", groomFatherName);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@groomAge", groomAge);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@groomPhone", groomPhone);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@groomAddress", groomAddress);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@brideName", brideName);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@brideFatherName", brideFatherName);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@brideAge", brideAge);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bridePhone", bridePhone);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@brideAddress", brideAddress);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@registerName", registerName);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@registerPhone", registerPhone);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@registerAddress", registerAddress);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@referenceName", referenceName);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@referencePhone", referencePhone);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@referenceAddress", referenceAddress);


        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            lblMessage.Text = "Record inserted successfully";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "Unable to insert record";
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: but that shows 2 different button click events.... not 1.. what happened when it was 1

Comment: Are any errors thrown when you use `OnClick="btnWedRecInsert_Click1; btnWedRecInsert_Click2;"`?

Comment: Are these click events reused elsewhere such that somewhere there is a button that only triggers one event and another that only triggers the other event or something? Either way I would suggest extracting the logic of these events into their own methods. Then each of your event methods can just have a single line calling the appropriate method and then if you need another event that calls them both just create a new event method that calls both of your extracted methods.

Comment: yes im getting an error when compiling but what i need is to execute 2 queries at one button click just show me another way if it wont work

Comment: Use @Peter Morris post, call it using `OnClick="{fuctionName};"`

Comment: may I commend using `using` for `IDisposable` members ? i.e your DbConnection could be inside a `using`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the onClick event to btn_{NameOfYourButton}Click and then have

```
public void btn_{NameOfYourButton}Click() {
  btnWedRecInsert_Click1(); 
  btnWedRecInsert_Click2();  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should change your markup to:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnWedRecInsert" runat="server" Text="Insert" OnClick="btnWedRecInsert_Click" />
```

And change your codebehind to:

```
protected void btnWedRecInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
btnWedRecInsert_Click1();
btnWedRecInsert_Click2();
}
```

and for readability maybe you should change the name of the insert functions to

```
insertWedding1();
insertWedding2();
```

As of now I can't see any difference between the two insertfunctions. mayby you will change theese later but they're quite similar. How about making a function out of them with parameters so you don't have to write so much code : ) eg.

```
insertWedding(object paramWedding1);
insertWedding(object paramWedding2);
```

Comment: that worked thanks so much and well the difference is I'm inserting the values from different text boxes like reception one day and wedding the other day